# Is it possible to pipe a script to WScript?

Tags: windows, stdin, wsh

I would like to execute a simple VBScript/JScript generated by my application using the Windows Script Host (wscript.exe or cscript.exe) without generating a temporary script file.

I did not find a command line option to read the script form the standard input stream, but i did find several places in the WWW that document a WScript error message "Can't read script from stdin."

[MSDN Windows Script Host Reference - Error Messages](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e35tfdf7%28v=vs.84%29.aspx%20MSDN%20WScript%20error%20message)

So is there a hidden command line option to read the script from standard in?

Currently my program generates a small script and writes it to a temporary file. Then it creates a sub process running `cscript.exe`, waits for it to complete and then deletes the temporary file again. I would like to get rid of the temporary file and pass the script directly to the Script Host, if that's possible. (e.g. piping it to the `cscript.exe` or passing it as part of the command line arguments similar to the /c command line option of `cmd.exe`)

Comment: Can you post an example ? generate a vbscript from what ? please explain more !

Comment: You can execute your code string in your current process, or do you require to to run in a new process?

Comment: @AlexK. Can you elaborate? I'm interested and how you would pass dynamic script to the `cscript.exe` process without a temp file.

Comment: I mean that if the code does not need to run in a separate process he could run his string in the current process via .Execute or the ScriptControl

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short answer is No unfortunately. The WScript Engine does not provide a way to pass script either piped or via the command arguments, the only option is using `StdIn` to interpret and process the commands *(expand on this below)*.

---

### Using `StdIn` to interpret and Execute Code Direct from the Command Line

Wasn't sure myself but wanted to test it out...

> Worth noting that the testing below still requires a script to interpret the input which is probably not going to fit the requirement but is so generic I wouldn't class it as a temporary script.

The issue I can see is the more complex the code you want to pass in the harder it will be to pipe through to the `cscript.exe` program.

Here is a simple example that just pipes a `MsgBox()` call to `cscript.exe`.

Command line:

```
echo MsgBox("test piping") | cscript.exe /nologo "test.vbs"
```

Contents of `test.vbs`

```vb
Dim stdin: Set stdin = WScript.StdIn
Dim line: line = stdin.ReadAll

Call ExecuteGlobal(line)
```

**Handling Multiple Lines on the Command Line**

Piping multiple lines from `echo` isn't going to be easy it may work better if you use a character as a delimiter to break the commands up after being passed in. So for example;

```
echo MsgBox("test piping")^^^^Msgbox("test Complete") | cscript.exe /nologo "test.vbs"
```

then use

```
Split(stdin.ReadAll, "^")
```

to break up the command lines to execute.

---

Here is a more complex example;

Command Line:

```
echo Dim i: i = 1^^^^i = i + 2^^^^MsgBox("i = " ^^^& i) | cscript /nologo "test.vbs"
```

<strike>Contents of `test.vbs`:</strike>

```vb
Dim line Dim stdin: Set stdin = WScript.StdIn

For Each line In Split(stdin.ReadAll, "^")   
  'Takes each line from StdIn and executes it.
  Call ExecuteGlobal(line)
Next
```

*Made a rod for my own back by using `^` as the delimiter as this has special meaning in the command line and needs to be escaped (which just so happens to be `^`), plus the fact it has to be escaped again when piped hence the `^^^^`.*

Realised that breaking the lines down and executing them individually could cause more problems *(for example a `Function` definition would fail)*. This made me re-think the approach and found it should be even simpler.

```vb
Dim stdin: Set stdin = WScript.StdIn
Dim input: input = Replace(stdin.ReadAll, "^", vbCrLf)

Call ExecuteGlobal(input)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But it is not a solution to my question as I would still need to generate the test.vbs. I was looking for a solution without temporary files, i.e. with no persisted script files at all.

Comment: @niks Then the answer is no. Although you could class this as a temporary file it's completely independent of any dynamic code you pass in from the command line and it's the closest to a solution as you will get.

Comment: @niks I've updated the answer sorry I can't be more help.

Comment: Thanks again for your answer. I accepted it.  "No" was the answer I expected anyway. I was just wondering if there is something I missed, because of the linked MSDN error message documentation.

Comment: @niks The error there is misleading and does not refer to loading scripts dynamically in `cscript.exe` it is actually associated with opening script and occurs due to permission or corruption issues.

Comment: Very good! Using one-liner based in your answer: `ExecuteGlobal WScript.StdIn.ReadAll`. Line spliting may be done in batch: `(ECHO WScript.Echo "Line 1"&ECHO WScript.Echo "Line 2")|CSCRIPT //NOLOGO EXEC.VBS`

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a way to pipe a script to wscript (cscript actually) to do a potentially long running task during shutdown for a Windows service, and did not want to wait for it to complete in order to delete the temp script file. What I settled on was for the script to delete the file itself when it is finished:

```
' do work
Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
strPath = Wscript.ScriptFullName

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
objFSO.DeleteFile(strPath)
```