# Simplifying dynamic choices within a VBScript

Tags: vbscript, parameters

I've written a nice little VBScript that manages to replace a cumbersome i.e. slow delete/import/export routine in FileMaker. I would like to be able to generalise it by passing in a list of columns to concatenate rather than hard coding them in a switch statement (or equivalent).

I'd like to pass in a third parameter, say a string like "3,8,1,2"...

## EDIT

To make it explicitly clear what I'm asking. I have no issue handing in a third param. What I'm looking for is a VBScript-ish way to simplify the going from

```
"3,8,1,2"
```

to

```
objDst.WriteLine fields(2)+" "+fields(7)+" "+fields(0)+" "+fields(1)+vbTab+"1"
```

In other languages I do something with a lambda function, or evaulated code, or a Yield...

Here's the basic code as it stands:

```
Option Explicit
Dim objFs, objSrc, objDst, strLine, fields, value

If Wscript.arguments.count < 2 Then
    Wscript.echo "Usage: " + Wscript.ScriptName + " <input-file> <output-file>"
    Wscript.quit
End If

Set objFs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objSrc = objFs.OpenTextFile(Wscript.Arguments.item(0))
Set objDst = objFs.CreateTextFile(Wscript.Arguments.item(1))

While Not objSrc.atEndOfStream
    strLine = objSrc.ReadLine()
    If strLine <> "" Then
        ' Now build key string - fields 3, 8, 1, and 2
        fields = Split(strLine,vbTab)
        ' Write out the line to the destination file
        objDst.WriteLine fields(2)+" "+fields(7)+" "+fields(0)+" "+fields(1)+vbTab+"1"
    End If
Wend

objSrc.Close
objDst.Close
```

Any ideas ;-) ?

[ and feel free to crit the code. VBScript is not my first language]

Comment: Your already working with `WScript.Arguments` so just add another one and use `Split()` to parse the delimited string.

Comment: :-) yes, had got that far. I was more interested in replacing the `fields(2)+" "+fields(7)+" "+fields(0)+" "+fields(1)` bit with something appropriate. In another language I'd use a lambda function or Yield or something...

Comment: Not really using an array and concatenating the result is what I would do, VBScript is a scripting language not a fully fledged programming language don't expect too much. One thing I would say is use `&` to concatenate your strings rather then `+` while both work the true concatenation character is `&` and more widely used.

Comment: You could use an `EVal()` but wouldn't recommend sanitising your input first.

Comment: Looking at [this](http://icodealot.com/dynamic-methods-in-vbscript/) for a dynamic approach. Looks funkily close to what I need.

Comment: It just depends how complex you want to go, `Eval()`, `Execute()` and `ExecuteGlobal()` are very useful for executing dynamic code, but like in my previous comment you will need to be careful executing code directly from script input.

Answer (score 1):

Irritating as it may be, here's an answer to doing it dynamically in VBSCript.

Turns out that you can redefine a function, or in fact **define** a function within a VBScript. Who knew?

This test script takes a parameter which is a list of fields, and uses it to build a function which it then applies to some test data.

```
Option Explicit
Dim fieldList, fields, x

If Wscript.arguments.count < 1 Then
    Wscript.echo "Usage: " & Wscript.ScriptName & " ""Key,field,list"""
    Wscript.quit
End If

fieldList = Wscript.Arguments.item(0)

Sub setupProcess()
    Wscript.echo "Set-up processLine() for passed in parameters: " & fieldList
    fields = Split(fieldList,",")
    '
    ' Runtime method-overloading
    '
    ExecuteGlobal _ 
    "Option Explicit: " & _
    "Function processLine( values ): " & _
    "    processLine = values("& Join(fields,")&"" ""+values(") &"): " & _
    "End Function:"
End Sub

setupProcess() ' set-up function dynamically

' test examples
Wscript.echo processLine(Split("a,b,c,d,e,g,h,i,j,k,l",","))
Wscript.echo processLine(Split("q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z",","))
Wscript.echo processLine(Split("1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9",","))
```

Here's some output:

```
H:\>CScript C:\Users\rdyce1\Desktop\test.vbs "1,2,3,6,3,6,3"
Microsoft (R) Windows Script Host Version 5.8
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Set-up processLine() for passed in parameters: 1,2,3,6,3,6,3
b c d h d h d
r s t w t w t
2 3 4 7 4 7 4

H:\>CScript C:\Users\rdyce1\Desktop\test.vbs "1,1,2,2,5"
Microsoft (R) Windows Script Host Version 5.8
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Set-up processLine() for passed in parameters: 1,1,2,2,5
b b c c g
r r s s v
2 2 3 3 6
```

Thanks to [Justin Biard's blog post](http://icodealot.com/dynamic-methods-in-vbscript/).

Comment: What about doing the Split() inside the dynamic function, would be a little bit nicer.

Comment: Have [talked about this in the past](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36449210/692942) just your initial question wasn't very clear, good find though.

Comment: Thanks Lankymart - have made your suggested changes - tests obvioulsy produce same output, but better encapsulation. Thanks.

Comment: I was actually referring to the `Split()` in `processLine()`, seems untidy passing it in like that when the command line is just going to `a,b,c,d,e,g,h,i,j,k,l` etc.

Answer (score 0):

While I wouldn't do this you can use [`EVal()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0z5x4094%28v=vs.84%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to evaluate your expression as a list of array values, which cuts out the `Split()` but still not much more useful.

```vb
Dim args: Set args = WScript.Arguments
Dim data

data = EVal("Array(" & args(0) & ")")
WScript.Echo data(1)
```

Output:

```
>cscript.exe /nologo test.vbs "3,8,1,2"
8
```

> **CAUTION:** If you do use this method [`Eval()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0z5x4094%28v=vs.84%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) is very powerful so I'd recommend sanitising any input first or at the very least knowing exactly what arguments you are passing into it.